# Javascript nested methods / sequence in which they are executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am new to Javascript and having a problem. In my script I want to get the last file that was added to a folder. This works fine, but when I want to use that name of the file afterwards it doesn't work. Because on the console I can see that the script did not execute in sequence I would expect.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var direc = path.join(__dirname, '../', 'uploads');
var url = 'start';

console.log('1');

fs.readdir(direc, function(err, list){
  list.forEach(function(file){
    current = fs.statSync(direc + '/' + file).ctime;
    if (current > temp ){
      url = file;
      console.log('2');
    }
    temp = fs.statSync(direc + '/' + file).ctime;
  })
  console.log('3');
});

console.log(url);   
console.log('4');
```

And the result in the console is:

```
1
start
4
3
2
```

Why doesnt javascript execute in a way that you would predict, meaning from 1-->2-->3-->url-->4?

Comment: why can I never find the canonical answer to this question when I want it...?

Comment: @JamesThorpe no, the other one! :)

Comment: @Alnitak Haha... I prefer to use the "modified in function" one for Q's like this, as OP isn't necessarily trying to return from a function - they're both useful though

Comment: @JamesThorpe if they haven't written this code into a function, they should have! :p

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're performing an `asynchronous` operation. Instead of waiting for the **response**, the execution continues immediately and the statement after the request call is execute.

You can fix this using a `callback` function.

```
function read(callback){
   fs.readdir(direc, function(err, list){ 
      list.forEach(function(file){
         current = fs.statSync(direc + '/' + file).ctime;
         if (current > temp ){
           url = file;
         }
         temp = fs.statSync(direc + '/' + file).ctime;
      })
      callback(url);
    });
}

read(function(url){
     console.log(url); 
});
```

Here are possible approaches in order to solve your problem.

- **Promises with async/await** (`ES2017+`)
- **Callbacks**
- **Promises with then()** (`ES2015+`)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, when I use the code you supplied the console only says '1' and then the page goes into a loop for minutes.
And which one your suggested approcaches would you choose to solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

It happens because JavaScript's `fs.readdir` function is **asynchronous**. It means it does not guarantee that it will be called in the same order you have it in your code.

You might want to take a look at:

- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: if `console.log` was async.. oh my god.